# What is the best way to solve these eqations with 4 unknowns?

Tags: linear-algebra, puzzle

There are 4 equations, and four unknowns to solve for:

$2A+2B=34$

$A+B+C+D=22$

$A+2B+D=31$

$B+3C=17$

Find the value of A, B, C, D.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: (And inb4 some smartarse asks, no this is not homework.  I'm 28, not 14.  This problem is from one of those puzzle book things, and its been so long since I did mathematics that I can't remember how to solve these types of problems.)

Comment: Asking whether or not a question is homework is not being a smartarse.

Comment: You can use any method in solving system of equations for this problem. $a = 6,   b = 11,   c = 2,   d = 3$

Comment: from the first equation you get $A+B=17$.subtract that from second which gives you $C+D=5$. and from third $B+D=14$.From these last two equation you get $B-C=9$. Your last equation gives you $B+3C=17$. Subtract these two to get $4C=8$. and solve from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- Method 1: Set up and solve the system using Gaussian Elimination.
- Method 2: Use substitution and eliminate variables, for example, from the fourth equation we have $B = 17-3C$, substitute into other equations and eliminate and continue this process.
- Method 3: From equation 1, we have $A+B = 17$, like Method 2, use it to reduce and solve.

You should get:

$$A = 6, B = 11, C = 2, D = 3$$

Comment: Method 3: [Ask WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[{2A%2B2B%3D34%2CA%2BB%2BC%2BD%3D22%2CA%2B2B%2BD%3D31%2CB%2B3C%3D17}%2C{A%2CB%2CC%2CD}]). ;-)

Comment: @VedranŠego: Indeed, if it is a puzzle, why not! :-)

Comment: @RahulNarain If you're talking about $\color{red}{1}7$, I've fixed that at about the same time that you wrote your comment. ;-)

Comment: @VedranŠego that WolframAlpha thing was very cool.  I take it that it is doing a Gaussian elimination there?

Comment: @E_L It's hard to say. I think Wolfram does not make such information public. I would expect [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) with complete pivoting, but `Solve` can be used on more than just linear systems, and - at least in some cases - it seems to use inverses.

Comment: Green ticks look good on you! +1